# sparse matrix Coordinate Storage format: convert from row-major to column-major

Tags: c++, matrix

I have two c++ function (foo, goo) operating with sparse matrix in Coordinate Storage Format,
that is, the matrix is given as 3 arrays: row_index[nnz], column_index[nnz], value[nnz]
where nnz is the number of non-zero elements.

foo returns the sparse matrix "by row-major order", as example:

- 1  1   4.000000
- 1  2   4.000000
- 2  1   6.000000
- 2  3   8.000000
- 3  3  10.000000

goo, instead, need the vector to by sorted "by column-major order", that is:

- 1  1   4.000000
- 2  1   6.000000    //this is changed
- 1  2   4.000000    //this is changed
- 2  3   8.000000
- 3  3  10.000000

How can I make this conversion in the most efficient way?

Additional info:
goo also supports Compressed Column format.

Answer (score 0):

if you have control over the data structure over execution, a clean, efficient way would be to store the format as array of structs, then sort w.r.t to the relevant column, for example

```
typedef std::tuple<size_t,size_t,double> elem_t;
// std::get<0>(storage[i]) is the row index of the i-th non-zero
// std::get<1>(storage[i]) is the col index of the i-th non-zero
// std::get<2>(storage[i]) is the value of the i-th non-zero
std::vector<elem_t> storage;
// this sort can be parallel
std::sort(storage.begin(),storage.end(),[](const elem_t& L, const elem_t& R){return std::get<1>(L)<std::get<1>(R);});
```

If not, one can write a functor to do index sort according to the column, and permute afterwards. This is of course a lot more messy and would incur memory overhead.

Comment: the two functions are provided by two separate libraries; so I have no control over the data structure.